# How make Eclipse instrument classes at build time?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, bytecode, instrumentation, bytecode-manipulation

Sometimes I have to perform some custom bytecode transformation. 
I have used mainly asm and javaassit.

Inside eclipse usually I run my code with the -javaagent jvm parameter. Outside eclipse I use maven, ant, or the command prompt to invoke the weavers before running the application code.

But the point is that: I would like to perform instrumentation at build time inside eclipse.

- What is the best way to do it?
- Is there an already made plugin that I can connect to by implementing some api?
- May I script this with eclipse monkey?
- May I use an ant builder and invoke my weaver with it?
- Should I look at the AspectJ plugin (must be huge) and try to figure out how to make my own plugin?
- Should I look at the some other plugin to get inspiration?

Thanks.

Comment: You could take a look at Project Lombok's eclipse plugin, they do bytecode generation from eclipse.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an annotation processor. This way you will be able to use it with ant, maven and any IDE (not only Eclipse).
Here is an example:
http://java.dzone.com/news/using-java-6-processors

Comment: There is no point in the annotation processor lifecycle to modify bytecode.

Comment: You should be able to manipulate the class files directly. All you need to know is their location and the fact that they have been created. See this project http://projectlombok.org/

Comment: I've tried this. With sun's java compiler. The .class are generated after the last annotation processor round.

Comment: AFAIK, lombok changes the compiler's AST tree, not the byte code. Plus what lombok does is a violation of the annotation processor contract. It casts the processor interfaces, like Elemen and TypeElement into the sun's compilers classes.